# Why Sigma 24-70 f2.8 OS (Optical Stabilization ) is not working on Nikon D5600?

Tags: sigma, nikon-d5600

The OS (Optical Stabilization) for Sigma 24-70 f2.8 (https://www.sigma-global.com/en/lenses/a017_24_70_28/) is not working when using it with Nikon D5600. Has anyone faced such issue?

I also have a Sigma 100-400 with OS and it works nicely with my camera

Comment: Just to double-check: OS is enabled on both the lens, and the camera body? (I'm sure you've checked that, just want to make sure). Also, are you sure it's not working? What are the symptoms / behavior?

Comment: D5600 has no inner stabilization. I tried to shake the lens gently, just to test the stabilization. Previously tried on my sigma 100-400 I can see the difference easily, but with 24-70 I do not see any difference with OS being enabled